# ProxyPass Prompting for Username and Password

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

In my secure apache2 site file, I have

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>    
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>

...

ProxyPass /subdirectory http://another.site/anotherdir/
ProxyPass /subdirectory/ http://another.site/anotherdir/

<Location /anotherdir/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When my users hit the proxypass, they are prompted for an apache username and password.  How can I bypass the apache username and password?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using apache authentication ?

Comment: I am using apache authentication in different subdirectories (https://192.168.1.1/sub) but the proxypass target isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `RequestHeader unset Authorization` to your config before the `ProxyPass` lines.

Comment: That seems to work. Will this affect my apache-protected subdirectories?

Comment: Did you test those protected subdirs?

Comment: I did but I just want to be extra sure. The protected subs prompted me for a username and password

Comment: Great.  Then your config should be good now.